# Set curent page in PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm currently using a PagerTitleStrip in my app - with 3 screens - and everything works great - but I want when the app first starts to display the second screen! So basically the user can see the second screen and swipe right for the first screen and left for the third screen.

Can anyone tell me how can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Silly question - I just had to set the second screen in the ViewPager using setCurrentItem().
Thank you for you're help!

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the second screen in the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) using `setSelectedNavigationItem()` method of `ActionBar`. The `PagerTitleStrip` should be updated accordingly.

Comment: I've done something like this in my code getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1); but I get a 08-20 16:54:01.644: E/AndroidRuntime(24791): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Comment: Ok. It means your ActionBar does not know about the viewPager, or the ViewPager does not have an adapter. Can you post a bit of code ? (creation of the pager, the pager adapter, the fragments)

Comment: Here;s how I create the adapter that will return a fragment for each  of the three primary screens. mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

  // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
  mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

Comment: can you edit the question and add the code & full error stack ? It will be easier to help you :)